# How to have custom POST requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I have a WelcomeController which for the moment only has the action GET#index which does nothing (the view renders a welcome message) and is also the root path.
In this view, I want to have two buttons to perform action1 and action2. I've managed to get the result I want with action1 button by doing this:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def action1
    ... #code
  end
end
```

views/welcome/index.html.slim

```
h1 = "Welcome"
br
= form_tag url: welcome_index_path do
  - if user_signed_in?
    = submit_tag "Action1"
```

And in routes.rb:

```
get 'welcome/index'
post '/welcome/index', to: 'welcome#action1'
```

I wanna add now the second button in a similar way, but when I click on it, it performs Action1 (I assume it's because the re-routing of post request for welcome/index in routes.rb.

How do I properly do this, so that I can have as many actions that send POST requests as I want?

Comment: While you can do this you might want to start with a tutorial on how rails apps are built - what you are building is more like a bunch of remote procedure calls. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may go this [document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to learn more about routing in rails.

In this case, you may define your `routes.rb` like this:

```
resources :welcome, controller: 'welcome', as: 'welcome', only: [:index] do
  collection do
    post 'action_1'
    post 'action_2'
  end
end
```

Then you view will be:

```
= form_tag url: welcome_action_1_path do
  = submit_tag "Action1"

= form_tag url: welcome_action_2_path do
  = submit_tag "Action2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more about routing. Check Rails guide on routing, which will help you a lot. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

For action1, you probably want to set a different route.

```
get 'welcome/index'
post 'welcome/action1', to: 'welcome#action1'
```

That means an HTTP POST action to url `'welcome/action1'` will map to `action1` method in `welcome` controller.

You can keep on adding these.

```
post 'welcome/action2', to: 'welcome#action2'
```

You can also use other HTTP methods. Different HTTP methods to same url can be routed to different methods.

```
get 'welcome/action3', to: 'welcome#action3_get'
post 'welcome/action3', to: 'welcome#action3_post'
patch 'welcome/action4', to: 'welcome#action4'
delete 'welcome/action5', to: 'welcome#action5'
```

In addition, you can also set an alias for that route, similar to `welcome_index_path`, which is, after all, a path generated by rails helper that maps to `get 'welcome/index'` by default.

```
post 'welcome/action6', to: 'welcome#action6', as: 'welcome_action6'
```

Then you can use `welcome_action6_path` in your form tag too.